# Angular - How to execute code after render

Tags: angular, typescript

I need some help in deciding how to execute code after a component has been rendered in Angular 10.

I've discovered two methods on how to do this but each has some kind of concern or unease and I wish to know which one to go with or if there's an alternative:

**Method 1: AfterViewChecked**

```
class UserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  ...

  users = [];
  doRenderCallback = false;

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.doRenderCallback) {
      // Perform JQuery
      this.doRenderCallback = false;
    }
  }

  private addUser(user): void {
    this.users.push(user);
    this.doRenderCallback = true;
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

I would set a boolean flag whenever a new user is added and then in `ngAfterViewChecked` it checks for the flag and then executes some given jQuery on the newly populated HTML element.

However this assumes to perform the jQuery on the last user added, so if `addUser` is called multiple times at once (like loading in existing data from a server) then it doesn't work.

**Method 2: setTimeout**

```
class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  users = [];

  private addUser(user): void {
    this.users.push(user);
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Perform JQuery
    });
  }
}
```

Using `setTimeout` directly after updating the users property is cleaner since it keeps the jQuery code in the same function and doesn't require a flag property. However, I feel unsure if this is reliable and I can't seem to find many answers or documentation to support this.

Can someone please give me advice?

Comment: 1. Don't mix jQuery with Angular, its best practice to use either one rather than combining them 2. It would be MUCH easier to use a service to track your business logic, thereby keeping your component light weight.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with wrapping an existing jQuery plugin in an Angular component, provided you know what you're doing. Based on the question, the OP is already aware of the fact that the two things don't play well together, and has asked a legitimate question. jQuery is marginal to the answer to the provided question (How to execute code after render?) and is there only to provide more context.